# MySQL Stored procedure won't fetch the whole table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

First I tried this, (MySQL/phpmyadmin)

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `tempcheck`() NO SQL 

BEGIN 
SET @query_string = 'SELECT * FROM properties'; 
PREPARE query_statement FROM @query_string; 
EXECUTE query_statement; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE query_statement; 

END
```

This just fetches the first record of the table 'properties'. The table has more than one value. When I sqlquery 'select * from properties;' it returns the whole table.

I even tried this simple method

```
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM properties';

END
```

Tried many stackoverflow Q&As. They all suggest that I make a temp table. Even if I do, how will it return the whole table when it doesn't return the entire table here in the first place. CAN a mysql stored procedure actually return a whole table or NOT. if it can, then how?

Comment: Remove the DEALLOCATE statement from proc. You have no need to deallocate manually because it will be freed automatically once session is closed.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Return the multirow resultset to your application? If so, your application will have to read the resultset row by row from the mySQL server. If for some reason you have to use a stored procedure rather than just a SELECT for this, debug your application by getting the SELECT to work (IN YOUR APPLICATION), then switch to using your simple stored procedure.

Comment: @Nav What is your problem? Do u need to store the entire table records to a variable???

Comment: @Romil I already tried removing deallocating. check my second piece of code

Comment: @OllieJones Yes, I am trying to return multiple records. In other words I want this procedure to do exactly what that simple SQL statement would do. I tried test running this procedure in phpmyadmin, it did return the record from table 'properties', but it just returns one record I want the whole table. I presumed if phpmyadmin can return this properly, then I can make my PHP app to do the same. Are you saying if I call this procedure from a PHP app it will return the whole table?

Comment: @Prathap I just need the procedure to execute the SQL statement and return exactly like it would when I execute a normal SQL statement. because I can't get my head around this simple execution first. Initially I wrote a procedure based on an SQL query and the query worked but the procedure didn't (like in it worked but only return a single record)

Comment: I NEED MULTIPLE RECORDS!!! somebody help me please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys thank you all for your help. One of my colleagues helped me fix it. Apparently it's a bug in phpmyadmin. phpmyadmin won't return more than one record

Comment: Right. phpmyadmin doesn't know, and isn't set up to guess, that you want a multiple-row resultset when you invoke a sp.